# Deleting DataFrame row in Python Pandas based on column values

Tags: pandas, ipython, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a dataset and I want to delete rows from the dataframe based on 2 or column values of that row . 
For example - I have data frame about all the TV Shows in US , and I need to delete the a particular rows of a TV Show  based on the  the season of the TV SHow and the episode . 
Like I need to delete rows of the  TV SHow - Gotham but only the rows containing season 4 and episode 10 .

Would really appreciate if I could get help regarding this .

Comment: This is not really a duplicate of that question.  That question asked about conditioning on a single column value.  This question asks about a condition that involves multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a boolean series to index the dataframe. Something like:

```
conditions = np.logical_and(
     df.col1 == "Gotham",
     df.col2 == 4)

# or, if you need more than two columns in your condition do this:
conditions = np.all(np.array(
    [df.col1 == "Gotham",
     df.col2 == 4,
     df.col3 == 10]), axis=0)

df = df[~conditions]
```

Addressing the follow up question below, we have

```
conditions = np.logical_and(
     df.name == "Gotham",
     df.year == 2011)

df["model_ind"][conditions] = 1
```

Comment: Thank you Bob for the reply , really appreciate that  , the code worked fine ,

Comment: No problem!  Feel free to accept the answer.

Comment: I was  facing another issue , 
In this issue , I want to replace a value of a column named - 'model_ind' to 1 , 
If, the Name of the show is Gotham and the year is 2011. 

Would really appreciate if you could help me with it , 

Thank you,

Comment: That was perfect , Thank you so much 
I would like to ask one last doubt to you , 

I have a column , called Lnc which is of type integer , and I want to create another column value in the same data frame named Log_Lnc which is log base2 value of the column Lnc . 
Would really appreciate if you could help me with that

Comment: And i was trying to apply the same logic you explained to the following code, 
But it was not working - 
if mdy(9,24,2007)<=(target_date) and (target_date)<mdy(9,22,2008) then Season=2007;

Comment: Can you edit your question with a description of the problem?

Comment: I had 2 different issues : 

1)I I was trying to apply the logic you explained in the above code about replacing the value of column , 
 to the following code, 
 if mdy(9,24,2007)<=(target_date) and (target_date)<mdy(9,22,2008) then Season=2007;

But it was not working, 

2) And my second issue was - 
I have a column , called Lnc which is of type integer , and I want to create another column value in the same data frame named Log_Lnc which is log base2 value of the column Lnc